# Using Set Wkb feature

Tags: vba, excel

I am using some code that should set a workbook as a variable and then call upon it at a later date. I belive i need to do this as through the code I am jumping between 3 - 4 different workbooks.

However when i go to use this line of code `wkbDestinationBook.Sheets(c10).Select` I get a

> Select Method of Worksheet Class failed

To define my `wkbDestinationBook` i used the line

`Set wkbDestinationBook = ActiveWorkbook` in a previous `Sub` and is defined as `Global wkbDestinationBook As Excel.Workbook`

`Worksheet(c10)` is no issue as I've used that line when the workbook is active and no issue found

I am at a loss on what/how to solve this error. Thanks

Comment: use `Public wkbDestinationBook As Excel.Workbook` in the declarations area at the top of a module code sheet above and outside of any sub.

Comment: Does the decleration not need to be global as its used in multiple sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly simple solution to this.

I changed the line `wkbDestinationBook.Sheets(c10).select` to `wkbDestinationBook.Sheets(c10).activate` now works without any issue

Answer (score 2):

Public variables should not be declared inside a Sub. If you declare a Variable inside a Sub, this variable will be valid only for this procedure.
You need to declare as following example:

```
Option Explicit

Public wkbDestinationBook As Excel.Workbook

Sub YourSub ()
    'Your code
    'You can set the value of the Public Variable wkbDestinationBook
End Sub
```

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html

Comment: What is the difference between a `Global` and `Public` variable

Comment: Maybe this can answer your question> https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-declare-a-global-variable-in-VBA

Comment: `Global` and `Public` are the same thing. `Global` is just "the old way"